# *_set attributes on Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a very basic question about `django.db.models`.

In this [official django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/), if you search for word "`choice_set`", you will see that variable "`choice_set`" is not declared anywhere, though magically, we can start using it in the code.

I wonder, what does `django.db.models.Model` do that magically created the *_set variable, and what other variables does it create?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get a full list of the attributes of a class, both those you defined and the ones that are defined for it, using the `dir` function, just do

```
 dir(Poll)
```

You'll end up with something that looks a little like (though not exactly- I'm constructing it in a roundabout way):

```
['DoesNotExist', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', '__class__', '__delattr__',
'__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__',
'__init__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__',
 '__weakref__', '_base_manager', '_default_manager', '_deferred', '_get_FIELD_display', 
'_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD', '_get_next_or_previous_in_order', '_get_pk_val', 
'_get_unique_checks', '_meta', '_perform_date_checks', '_perform_unique_checks', '_set_pk_val', 
'clean', 'clean_fields', 'curve_set', 'date_error_message', 'delete', 'full_clean', 'objects', 
'pk', 'prepare_database_save', 'save', 'save_base', 'choice_set',
'serializable_value', 'unique_error_message', 'validate_unique']
```

That's a lot of values! We can see exceptions like `DoesNotExist` and `MultipleObjectsReturned`, along with the most important one, `objects`. But some of these attributes weren't added by Django. If you do `dir(object())` you'll find a list of the attributes in *all* objects:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Mostly you can ignore the ones that start and end with two `__`. Most of the others were added by Django.

---

As for how and where it actually sets these: Django sets most of each new model's attributes dynamically using the `models.Model` metaclass. The first thing to know is that you can add a member or method to a class dynamically, using the `setattr` function:

```
class X:
    pass
setattr(X, "q", 12)
print X.q  # prints 12
```

That's how it can create new attributes just based on the name of your attribute.

In the tutorial, the important line that allows it to start defining these extra attributes is:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
```

This means that the `Poll` class inherits the `models.Model` class (which belongs to Django). Inheritance has many useful properties- basically, the `Poll` class inherits some of the behavior that the `models.Model` class has set up- but the place it defines most of these new attributes is in the Model [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python). Metaclasses are a tricky concept, but basically they serve as a recipe for creating new classes, and by defining one, Django gets to step in right when the `models.py` metaclass is being defined, and define any new .

The code for the Model metaclass can be found [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py) (starting at line 55)- it's a set of code that is actually step-by-step creating a class from the ground up. As complicated as it looks, you can get a lot out of it just by looking at the variable names. For instance, look at the promisingly named `add_to_class` method:

```
def add_to_class(cls, name, value):
    if hasattr(value, 'contribute_to_class'):
        value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
    else:
        setattr(cls, name, value)
```

Outside of the one special case of `'contribute_to_class` (not important for your interest), this is a method for adding a new attribute (such as a method or a member) to a class. The places where it is called give us hints of what it is adding:

```
 class.add_to_class('DoesNotExist', subclass_exception(str('DoesNotExist') ...<truncated>...
```

Here it is adding the `DoesNotExist` exception, which is what is returned if you ask for a `Poll` that doesn't exist. (See for yourself by running `Poll.objects.get(pk=1337)`, or directly by typing in `Poll.DoesNotExist`).

But Django is actually even more complicated than that. The *specific* `_set` attribute you're asking about isn't constructed for every model- it's created when a field is related to another by a `ForeignKey` (as are your `Poll` and `Choice`). The various places where it gets assigned are very complicated, but it basically all comes back to this `get_accessor_name` function in [related.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py)

```
def get_accessor_name(self):
    # This method encapsulates the logic that decides what name to give an
    # accessor descriptor that retrieves related many-to-one or
    # many-to-many objects. It uses the lower-cased object_name + "_set",
    # but this can be overridden with the "related_name" option.
    if self.field.rel.multiple:
        # If this is a symmetrical m2m relation on self, there is no reverse accessor.
        if getattr(self.field.rel, 'symmetrical', False) and self.model == self.parent_model:
            return None
        return self.field.rel.related_name or (self.opts.object_name.lower() + '_set')
    else:
        return self.field.rel.related_name or (self.opts.object_name.lower())
```

That's just coming up with the name- tracing it back to figure out how it gets added to the class is no small feat. But I hope you see from this that Django has many chances to add attributes like this.

Comment: Wow, this goes into detail :)

Comment: Thanks David. I know there can be a lot, but can you name a few more commonly used attributes that might be magically created?

Comment: nice, nothing is better than someone else reading the code for you and point where to look.

Answer (score 11):

This is some `ForeignKey` magic :)

The `Choice` model has the attribute `poll`, which is a `ForeignKey` to a `Poll` object. Django adds the convenience method `choice_set` to `Poll` objects, which will give a `QuerySet` containing all `Choice` objects that reference that `Poll` Object.

So, given this (pseudo) code

```
myPoll = Poll(question='Is Django awesome?')
option_yes = Choice(poll=myPoll, choice='Yes')
option_no = Choice(poll=myPoll, choice='No')
```

You could later run

```
poll = Poll.objects.get(question='Is Django awesome?')
options = poll.choice_set.all()
```

and options would include the relevant `Choice` objects.

You can change the name of this attribute using the `related_name` option when defining the `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 2):

Choice has a ForeignKey to Poll, and Django auto-generates the convenience method Poll.choice_set() to access all the choices that refer to that poll.

There's a great article covering the topic of following relations backwards in the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Answer (score 1):

In the Document you are referring https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01

'_set' refers to the all the choices that relates to the Poll object, Since the Choice model has poll that is a Foreign Key to Poll of ID.

For Example:

Consider Poll table row(1,'How are you?','2014 7 3')

and Choice table

when you say

```
p = Poll.objects.get(id=1)
```

//now p is a Poll Object that holds <1,'How are you?','2014 7 3'>
    p.choice_set.create(choice="1st",votes=8)
// in Choice table it creates a row that refers poll ID 1 i.e Choice table row(1,1,'1st',8)

Basically _set refers to the tuples of the Choice table (poll) referring Poll table (ID)